# Has anyone discussed the computerisation of democracy?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, politics, democracy, work

Has anyone discussed the computerisation of democracy?

I read that a lot of middle class jobs are going to go missing soon, due to technological progress. Does that include government roles, such that the democratic process might become e.g. more obviously an unnecessary injustice?

Comment: See this [related post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37066/are-there-contemporary-arguments-against-democracy-as-inherently-flawed) and answers within, especially commando's and mozibur ullah's answers.

Comment: Also, you mention the automation of jobs as a possible cause. Remember that representative democracy concerns mostly the legislative branch of government (mostly, not entirely), while the jobs that are mostly likely to be automated will be mainly part of the bureaucracy, i.e. the lower levels of the executive branch which aren't chosen by elections.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing i asked a friend and they suggested https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethereum

Comment: "includ[ing] government roles" Do you mean an AI playing the role of Prime Minister, and so on ? If so, a lot of SciFi novels are available.

Comment: that too, but the general way that democracy and parliament may be undermined by its technological changes @MauroALLEGRANZA